# WebRTC disconnect not detectable

Tags: webrtc

I have an ASP.NET core back-end that is using SignalR (for signaling) and GStreamer to broadcast video streams to web clients. I'm testing with Chrome 117.0.5938.92. With the exception of some occasional GStreamer issues that I haven't figured out yet (https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/-/issues/1055), the streaming is working great.

I need to be able to reconnect the streams after network failures and I'm having issues setting this up. At this point, I've been testing with this methodology:

1. Connect to our work VPN.
2. Start back-end (on my local PC).
3. View stream in browser (on my local PC).
4. Disconnect VPN.

The result is that the video freezes. I believe that's due to the stream being set up with the IP address assigned to my local PC from the VPN and since it's no longer a valid IP, the stream stops. I think in this case, ICE needs restarted ([When can I consider a RTCPeerConnection to be disconnected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229785/when-can-i-consider-a-rtcpeerconnection-to-be-disconnected?rq=3)).

Where I'm having problems is detecting this situation. I have added event handlers everywhere I can think in order to detect there was an issue:

1. RTCPeerConnection.onconnectionstatechange
2. RTCPeerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange
3. MediaStreamTrack.onended

The onconnectionstatechange fires for connecting and connected states. The oniceconnectionstatechange fires for checking and connected states. So I know those event handlers are working.

Unfortunately, none of these seem to fire after I disconnect from the VPN. Even if I wait a long time, these don't fire. I was under the assumption that oniceconnectionstatechange would end up eventually happening with disconnected and/or failed, but it doesn't.

Next I went to look at WebRTC Internals. It definitely shows incoming packets going to 0. I would have thought that should mean MediaStreamTrack.onended gets fired, but it doesn't. I noticed after probably 30 seconds or so, an icecandidateerror happens, so I added an event handler for that. It happens twice.

One says:

> STUN binding request timed out.

The other says:

> TURN allocate request timed out.

I really don't think this is where I should detect network issues, but it seems to be the only place I can. Is there some reason I might not be getting the expected disconnected/failed ice connection state changes? Or for that matter, MediaStreamTrack.onended events considering the video has stopped.

**Edit 1**

I did a little more research. Noticed in WebRTC internals, that candidate pairs got switched when this happens. So I think that's why there is no disconnected/failed ice connection state. However, I don't understand why the video doesn't resume. The track does have a mute event which gets fired. It never fires an unmute event.